# How do I write an api that uploads files from aws client machine to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing an api that does some operations on files in the s3 bucket but that file needs to be uploaded from from aws client machines from different regions to s3 bucket using some other api .

Answer (score 0):

Prachi, 
I'm assuming that client machines are AWS EC2 Instances, these are the steps that you'll need to follow: "

1. Create IAM Role with permissions to that specific S3 bucket.
2. Attach IAM Role to EC2 to give client instances permission to interact with S3.
3. Use AWS SDK on client machines to put the file to S3 Bucket. You can either use [nodejs](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) or python [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html).

You should be able to get most of the things above on single google search.

Comment: Thanks Hasssan, but now I need to take files from azure also. Is there any way to write some common api to work for both. Actually I am new to cloud and the application where i am writing the api is on local machine not in the cloud. Can you help me with this issue ?

Comment: Parchi, that'll be another question but again you'll need to use azure sdk for that

Comment: Hi Hassan, can I do the 3rd point using some java api that will run on my local using aws sdk?

Comment: I mean can I write a single api on my local that will first put the file from aws ec2 instance to s3 and then do the required operation. I am able to upload to s3 bucket from my local and then do the required things using a java api. But still confused about putting it from aws to s3 bucket.

Comment: Yes, you can use AWS Access keys to send the files from local to S3 bucket. Then you can use sdk to get the file from S3 to EC2 to process if this is what you're looking for @prachi

Comment: I want my java api to copy or move a file from aws ec2 to s3 bucket in the  way similar to as I am putting a file into s3 bucket from my local machine using the java api in my local . @Hassan

Comment: Simply write the API just like you did on your local. API will run on EC2 and move files from EC2 EBS storage to S3.